# How can I add an action from a QGIS toolbar to my custom toolbar programatically?

Tags: qgis, python

I have a toolbar and I want it to have an already existing action, but checking the documentation I only found methods to add newly created actions, not already existing ones. Is there a way to do this?

The action I want to add is the Touch, Zoom and Pan tool from Map Navigation toolbar. I know I can reference it this way:

qgis.utils.iface.mapNavToolToolBar().actions()[0]

But there's nothing I can do with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need:

To add a new toolbar with:

```
toolbar = iface.addToolBar(u'My test')
```

Then, add the native action to the newly created `toolbar`:

```
# Example for pan
toolbar.addAction(iface.actionPan())
```

If you want the full list of actions, go to the [QGisInterface API documentation](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html).

Answer (score 5):

You might find it useful to look at the code generated by the **Plugin Builder** plugin, especially the **add_action()** method it generates, which is what hooks plugin icons into toolbars and menus.

This snippet looks promising...

```
if add_to_toolbar:
        self.toolbar.addAction(action)
```

You already found out how to get the existing `action` (a QAction object). Now you just need the snippet to get the toolbar you want to add the icon to.

Looking at the [API for qgisInterface](http://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a7dff31ec75b412fcfff93b61ca9af3eb) it seems there's already a method to let you create a toolbar...

```
myaction = qgis.utils.iface.mapNavToolToolBar().actions()[0]
mytoolbar = qgis.utils.iface.addToolBar("helloworld")
mytoolbar.addAction(myaction)
```

Just tried that in the console and it works. (If it doesn't appear, right click on the toolbar background and make sure 'helloworld' is checked)

**EDIT**

Just realised you want to glom onto an existing toolbar, which you haven't created yourself.

`QgisInterface` extends `QObject`, which has a `findChild(type,name)` method. However, running this from the console returns an empty list

```
print qgis.utils.iface.findChildren(PyQt4.QtGui.QToolBar,u'helloworld')
>>> []
```

Hopefully someone with more Qt knowledge can answer this. I think there may be an issue with reading data like this across threads :/